# Select default value if result is null

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hello friends I have been using this query to select some two fields on my Java application.

```
select distinct STU_LEVEL, STU_STREAM from STUDENT_MASTER_TABLE where STATUS_YEAR !=ACADEMIC_YEAR
```

Problem is if there is no data, the application is throwing a null pointer Exception. I need it such that if the fields are Null, then they are defaulted to 0. I have tried this with Coalesce but I can't seem to get it like:

```
select coalesce(distinct (STU_LEVEL,0),  (STU_STREAM, '0')) from STUDENT_MASTER_TABLE where STATUS_YEAR !=ACADEMIC_YEAR
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to use `COALESCE` twice like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(STU_LEVEL,0), COALESCE(STU_STREAM, '0')
FROM STUDENT_MASTER_TABLE
WHERE STATUS_YEAR !=ACADEMIC_YEAR
```

This will return 0 for STU_Level if it is NULL and 0 for STU_Stream if it is NULL.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e478f/2)

In response to your comment, it looks like you need to use a UNION get your desired results when no records are found:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(STU_LEVEL,0), COALESCE(STU_STREAM, '0')
FROM STUDENT_MASTER_TABLE
WHERE STATUS_YEAR !=ACADEMIC_YEAR
UNION 
SELECT 0,'0' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(STU_LEVEL,0), COALESCE(STU_STREAM, '0')
  FROM STUDENT_MASTER_TABLE
  WHERE STATUS_YEAR !=ACADEMIC_YEAR
)
```

And a sample fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29039/1

Comment: it is still returning Null with the columns labelled as COALESCE(STU_LEVEL,0) and COALESCE(STU_STREAM, '0')

Comment: @Stanley -- did you see the SQL Fiddle -- can you update it with your data to show what you mean?

Comment: Did see the the fiddle it works fine on the fiddle but I want it to work on My Database.

Comment: @Stanley -- :) I agree -- I was asking can you update the Fiddle with your data that is returning NULL and then I can look at it for you.  Also, is your data actually NULL or is it stored as a string 'NULL' value?  If string, COALESCE won't work.

Comment: And how will this behave if the table for example does not have any data.

Comment: STU_LEVEL is datatype Number STU_STREAM is varchar2

Comment: @Stanley -- I've updated the Fiddle to use those data types -- but it still works the same way.  If you could include sample data in an updated fiddle, I'd be happy to see why it's not working for you.

Comment: See what what happens when the table does not contain any records..Nothing comes. I am working with a table which at times will have no records at all.

Comment: @Stanley -- confused by your question -- if no data is in the table, then no results will come back (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b260/1) -- if you need a minimum of 0,'0' to be returned, then you need to add a union (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29039/1) -- hope this helps!

Comment: My question I think should be that when no data is found the default to Zero

Comment: On your second fiddle...Yes this is what I was looking for. Thanx

Comment: @Stanley -- great, glad it worked :)  I updated my answer to include that since it helped.  Best of luck!